# I am getting NAN error when trying to retrieve a value from a class?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting a 'NAN' error when I try to map().reduce() from a class method.

All the values are  dynamically updated when the form is submitted.

I want to store and add the values of price for each separate Waiter class and store it in the Waiter total.

I am not sure if the problem lies with in the function which is submitting the form or the class method addFood.

I have tried pasrseInt() a few ways but I am not sure of the correct syntax.

```js
/*

//Waiters Section

*/


//Waiter Constructor
class Waiter{
    constructor (name){
    this.name = name;
    this.order = [];
    this.total = 0;
    }
    
    
    //function to map() the price argument
    //and then reduce() to get the total
    addFood (item){
    this.order.push(item);
    this.total = this.order.map(o => o.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }

    
};





//Array to store waiters
const waiters = [
    new Waiter('Timo'),
    new Waiter('Lucian'),
    new Waiter('Arpi')
                  
];




const waitersEl = document.getElementById('waiters');

//Adding the waiters to the options menu
waiters.forEach(({name}) => waitersEl.options.add(new Option(name)));





    /*
    
    //Food Section Main
    
    */
    
    //Food Constructor
    class Item {
      constructor (item, price) {
      this.item = item;
      this.price = price;
      this.label = `${item} (${price})`;
      }
    }
    
    
    
    //Main food array
    const mainFood = [
        new Item ('Peene Primvera', 14),
        new Item("Lasagne", 14),
        new Item("Fillet Steak", 20)
    ];
    
    
    
    const foodMain = document.getElementById('menuMain');
    
    //Addin the options for each food and price item inside the dropdown menu
    mainFood.forEach(({label, item }) => foodMain.options.add(new Option(label, label)));
    
    
    
    
    /*
    
    //Fucntion for when the form is submited it adds the  
    
    */
    const formEl = document.getElementById('mainForm');
    
    formEl.onsubmit = function (e){
        
        //Selecting the choosen index from the user food and which waiter orderd //it which waiter 
        const foodItem = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;  
        
        const waiterName = waitersEl.options[waitersEl.selectedIndex].value;
        const waiter = waiters.find(({ name }) => name === waiterName);
        
        
        //Logic to check when submited if both feilds are true proceed 
        if (waiter && foodItem) {
            
            //Calling the function addFood from the Waiter
            //class to push the selection to the orders array
            //and then reduce it and put the total in the total argument
            waiter.addFood(foodItem);
            console.log(waiters);
        };
        
         
    
    
        return false; // prevents redirect/refresh
        
    };
```

```html
    <form id="mainForm" action="#">
      <select id="menuMain" name="foodOrder">
      </select>
      <select id="waiters" name="waiterSelection">
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

This is what I get now after I submit notice the total: NAN:

```
0: Waiter
addFood: ƒ (item)
name: "Timo"
order: ["Peene Primvera (14.5)", "Peene Primvera (14.5)"]
total: NaN
```

My desired result would be:

```
0: Waiter
addFood: ƒ (item)
name: "Timo"
order: ["Peene Primvera (14.5)", "Peene Primvera (14.5)"]
total: 29
```

Comment: please, indent and format your code to better readability

Comment: Please post code that we can run to reproduce your issue. Right now, your code does not even run.

Comment: `foodItem` is not really an `Item` object, it is a `string`.

Comment: Can you add the `Item` class definition ?

Comment: @Scott Marcus, This is the full code I am trying to run everything is set up and seems to work just the having the problem getting the total

Comment: @Titus, I see is their not away of just setting the .'price'  as a int to not have to worry about parsing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `<option>`s values to the `Item`'s label set it to the `Item`'s index in the `mainFood` array, this way it will be easy to get the `Item` object associated to the selected `<option>`.

Here is an example:

```
mainFood.forEach(({label, item }, index) => foodMain.options.add(new Option(label, index)));
```

And then:

```
const foodItemIndex = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value; 
const foodItem = mainFood[foodItemIndex];
```

Here is a working version:

```js
class Waiter {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = [];
    this.total = 0;
  }

  addFood(item) {
    this.order.push(item);
    this.total = this.order.map(o => o.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
};

const waiters = [
  new Waiter('Timo'),
  new Waiter('Lucian'),
  new Waiter('Arpi')

];

const waitersEl = document.getElementById('waiters');

waiters.forEach(({
  name
}) => waitersEl.options.add(new Option(name)));

class Item {
  constructor(item, price) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
    this.label = `${item} (${price})`;
  }
}

const mainFood = [
  new Item('Peene Primvera', 14),
  new Item("Lasagne", 14),
  new Item("Fillet Steak", 20)
];



const foodMain = document.getElementById('menuMain');

mainFood.forEach(({
  label,
  item
}, index) => foodMain.options.add(new Option(label, index)));


const formEl = document.getElementById('mainForm');

formEl.onsubmit = function(e) {

  const foodItemIndex = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;
  const foodItem = mainFood[foodItemIndex];

  const waiterName = waitersEl.options[waitersEl.selectedIndex].value;
  const waiter = waiters.find(({
    name
  }) => name === waiterName);

  if (waiter && foodItem) {
    waiter.addFood(foodItem);
    console.log(waiters);
  };

  return false; // prevents redirect/refresh
};
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" action="#">
  <select id="menuMain" name="foodOrder">
  </select>
  <select id="waiters" name="waiterSelection">
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much that make sense I was wondering why it was treating it as one string. So the reason was it was selecting the string in the <options>  rather than selecting form the mainFood array. Then this allows the class function to work properly as it can find the <.price> in its scope while executing?. :)

Comment: @Liam Yes, now when you call `waiter.addFood(....)` you pass this function an `Item` object instead of the value of the selected option. You can do the same thing for the waiters `<select>` so you won't have to get the selected waiter using `waiters.find(({ name }) => name === waiterName);`

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it appears as if some of the data inside `this.order` is not a number. `ParseInt()` will return `NaN` if a value is non-numerical.

If the data in here may possibly contain non-numerical data, you can default that index to `0` by using the double tilde operator `~~` (`Math.floor()`) which will return `0` in the cases where `parseInt()` will return `NaN`.

*This will fix the error, but depending on your needs, it may just be ignoring the problem. If this data is not intended to be in that array, I would advise investigating how it gets set there.*

```js
let total = [{
    price: 3
  }, {
    price: '5'
  }, {
    price: 'asdf'
  }].map(o => ~~o.price)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(total);
```